# What are the regulations involved in aerial advertising?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, commercial-operations

I often see small aircraft flying at a low altitude around beaches and the like with banner advertisements trailing behind them on a rope sort of structure. I have a few questions about them:

- What sort of permissions does it require (FAA) ?
- Is this hazardous in any way (I believe there would be some
  restrictions on this type of flight but is there an inherent danger
  involved in such flights) ?
- Are there any limits as to what altitude they are allowed to reach and
  any restricted air space that they are only allowed to fly in ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to get an [FAA waiver](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.3,Ch3,Sec1) (special permission), as required by [14 CFR 91.311](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1311):

> **§91.311   Towing: Other than under §91.309.**
>
> No pilot of a civil
> aircraft may tow anything with that aircraft (other than under
> §91.309) except in accordance with the terms of a certificate of
> waiver issued by the Administrator.

([91.309](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1309) is about towing gliders, so banner towing comes under 91.311.)

You need at least a private pilot certificate to tow banners - sport and recreational pilots aren't allowed to do it - but since most banner towing is paid work, in practice the pilot will usually have a commercial certificate (this is from the waiver instructions):

> When banner tow operations are conducted for compensation or hire, the
> pilot must have at least a limited commercial pilot certificate
> (without an instrument rating) and at least a valid second class
> medical certificate. An instrument rating is not a requirement for
> this operation.

The FAA has a [complete guide on banner towing](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/other/faa-fs-i-8700-1_rev1.pdf) and the waiver issue process has more administrative details. There don't seem to be many specific airspace requirements apart from the obvious, e.g. no towing in a TFR zone. But the FAA can impose more or less any conditions that they like as part of a waiver, and it will include the approved times and areas for operation.

(As an aside, it's widely believed in the pilot community that the permanent [stadium](http://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_4_3621.html) and [Disney](http://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_4_3634.html) TFRs are really there to prevent banner towing, not to increase security.)