# Advertising During Eclipse

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-planning

I imagine some companies will fly banners or sky-write during the eclipse.
Do all need to submit a plan and get it approved by the FAA?

Could a company actually be allowed to block the eclipse "a little" for a big
festival?

EDIT: The answer [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/what-are-the-regulations-involved-in-aerial-advertising) is not enough.  It doesn't even talk about filing a flight plan for a specific date.  So, are you saying any registered pilot (with the waiver to fly banners or to sky-write) could just wake up that morning and decide to advertise? That seems too easy and dangerous.

Comment: If I owned a business that planned on skywriting in front of people's view of a once in a lifetime event I would fear for my safety.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27112/62)

Comment: "So, are you saying any registered pilot (with the waiver to fly banners or to sky-write) could just wake up that morning and decide to advertise?" If you have the waiver and your flight plan is accepted, why not? "That seems too easy and dangerous." assessment based on?

Comment: All the same airspace rules which keep everyone safe apply as usual, including whether a flight plan is required. If the FAA feels that's not the case they would issue a TFR, as the linked question mentions.

Comment: "Whether a flight plan is required" is exactly what I asked and still don't know.  @Federico If you're saying a flight plan is required, please post an answer.  A few more details, like the FAA will make sure for safety that there aren't too many nearby flight plans, would be nice too.

Comment: about the flight plan requirement: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/when-is-a-flight-plan-required

Comment: Thanks everyone, please correct this answer if wrong:  No, no flight plan is required.  But, the pilot must of course be licensed and the aircraft must be registered (any towed banner would additionally need a FAA 91.311 waiver).  So yes, some guy (or many people, as long as they follow VFR) could spontaneously decide to go up and block the eclipse.  There are no special FAA rules imposed for the eclipse.  This seems to be a good opportunity for companies to get mass advertising (even without blocking the eclipse), so I'm curious to see if anyone takes advantage.